# Got HTTP response code 400 while sending escape string like "&amp;#"

Tags: http, escaping, special-characters, http-status-code-400

I am sending the content of an XML to a HTTP server in this way:

```
URL obj = new URL(targetURL);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""
        + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "de-DE");
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

The content of string urlParameters is:

```
mydata=<1000chars of XML content>@mydata=<1000chars of XML content>&...&mydata=<the rest chars of XML content>
```

Test cases:

1. If **urlParameters** does not contain special chars like plus sign (+),
   it works fine;
2. If **urlParameters** contain plus sign (+), the plus sign is missing on HTTP server;
3. if the plus sign is replaced with escaped string  **&#43;**, the client got the error code 400:

   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://192.168.101.51:80810/abs/P42t/bwb.receive_sync
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
   at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)

My Questions:

1. Why is the plus sign missing? (**Update**: the reason is as Han commented that the plus sign is considered as space in URL)
2. Can the string &#43; be sent to HTTP server in this way?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's following the URL convention, where '+' = "space". So it's not missing but done as google url search. Replace it with %20 you should be good to go. [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP]

Comment: Btw since the XML contains way lots of "=" signs you may want to checkout Java URL encoding to encode it. "POST" may be a better method - "If you are using the GET method, you are limited to a maximum of 2,048 characters"

Comment: @Han thanks a lot. But if the url parameters are coded on client, will they be decoded automatically on server side? Or URLDecoder.decode must be called on server explicitly?

Comment: Hard to say, it depends on client side. Cause it's depending if they do decode it but like you said if they have accepted + as " ", most likely yes they had decode it.

Comment: Btw, fyi &#43; wont work as & is to join a parameter, i.e. a=1&b=1. But I think you had got the overall gist now on URL encoding/decoding.